# ViewPager programmatically scrolling

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a simple `ViewPager`. Is there any possibilities programmatically scroll it every five seconds with usual animation?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Take a look at `ViewPager.setCurrentItem(int)` and combine it with a `TimerTask` or a `Handler`.

Example:

```
final ViewPager viewPager = ...;
final Handler h = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
final Runnable r = new Runnable() { 
    public void run() {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(0, true);
        h.postDelayed(r, 5000); 
    }
};
h.postDelayed(r, 5000);
```

Be sure to cancel the runnable when appropriate.

Comment: Thanks! I did't think, that it is so easy. Only one correction: you should call ViewPager.setCurrentItem(int, boolean)

Comment: Updated answer with code. Be sure you understand what is going on, it is easy to leak things.

Comment: you must change  h.postDelayed(r, 5000);  to  h.postDelayed(this, 5000);

Comment: In the line `h.postDelayed(r, 5000);` in the method `run()` is "r" not accessible. You could change it to `h.postDelayed(this, 5000);`, because it's a method in your runnable (which you want to access).

Comment: This is not working for me am using VerticalPageViewer

Comment: Calling `viewPager.setCurrentItem(0)` is sufficient as it defaults to smooth animation.